# Terrain map THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Tell me who knows about THREE.JS. I implement a map grid similar to the game SimCity 50x50. I rendered blocks of ground with different heights (as in the screenshot), now I want to smooth out the height transitions so that there is a smooth relief, while maintaining the 50x50 grid. As planned, everything should be like in the SimCity game: the user changes the type of landscape, change the relief of the landscape.

[Image: How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69wlU.jpg) - [Image: What I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFWP2.jpg)

Implemented as follows: there is a json array where for each cell its XZ coordinates are listed for placement on a 50x50 map and a Y coordinate for the height of the land block, as well as the type of terrain (grass, earth, stone, etc.). Each block of land is a BoxGeometry.

There were thoughts to somehow add vertices to the upper side and smooth out the transitions by their positions, but I did not find this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This *could* be accomplished with `BlockGeometry` objects, but that would be far more trouble than it's worth.  For example, you'd have to analyze the surrounding terrain to know how to rotate the `BlockGeometry` to modify it correctly, and you might have to rotate it again when the terrain is edited.  **< That's not to mention the number of objects; at your size of 50×50, you'd be adding 2,500 objects to the scene. >** A single mesh is much more natural in these circumstances.

First, notice that the map only comprises four cell shapes, not counting rotations: flat cells, cells that slope parallel opposite edges, cells that bend up to form a corner, and cells that bend down to form a corner.

[image: Four types of cells in the SimCity 2000 map]

Think of your terrain not as a set of blocks, but as one continuous surface quilted from square cells.  Each cell is a mesh of four triangles.

[image: Five vertices, four triangles, forming a square.]

Looking at a cell down the negative *y*-axis, starting at the top-left corner and moving clockwise around the cell, we'll label the vertices at the cell's corners *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d*.  We'll place a fifth vertex, *e*, at the exact middle of the cell when viewed from this perspective.  These vertices form four triangles, △*abe*, △*bce*, △*cde*, and △*dae*.

For any cell, the `Y` value that you're currently storing becomes the *y*-position of vertex *<del>a</del>**< e >***.

To get the *y*-position of vertex *b*, we look at the cell one column to the right.  The *y*-position of that cell's top-left corner (*a*), *i.e.*, that cell's stored `Y` value, is also the *y*-position of the top-right corner (*b*) of the cell we're currently building.  Similarly, the *y*-position of our current bottom-right corner (*c*) is the stored `Y` value of the cell down one row and to the right one column.  The *y*-position of our current bottom-left corner (*d*) is the stored `Y` value of the cell down one row.

Vertex *e* is a bit trickier, but it can be solved like this:

1. If any three of *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d* have the same *y*-position, then *e* shares that *y*-position (this is a level cell or a diagonal slope).
2. If two adjacent vertices of *a*, *b*, *c*, and *d* share one *y*-position and the other two share another *y*-position, then the *y*-position of *e* is the average of those two *y*-positions.
3. If neither *1* nor *2* is true, we have an error (because the *SimCity 2000* map didn't allow other types of geometry).

Now, actually generating the mesh is another matter, but there are plenty of tutorials available (via Google: [Procedural terrain meshes in ThreeJS](https://www.google.com/search?q=procedural+terrain+meshes+in+ThreeJS)).

**< I've created a proof of concept that you can see at https://pnichols04.github.io/sc2k-map/, with source code at https://github.com/pnichols04/sc2k-map. >**